# Alter result grails findAll or respond method

Tags: json, rest, grails, findall

Currently I'm developing a RESTFull using Grails. I use the findAll method to retrieve specific data:

```
def query = PlannedEvent.where{}
query = query.where{rooms.id == i }
respond query.findAll()
```

and the respond method to generate output:

```
{"class":"mp.ra.PlannedEvent","id":480,"baseEvent":{"class":"Event","id":1636},"equipment":[],"rooms":[{"class":"Room","id":22}]}
```

How can I alter the result so more information is given about the baseEvent and the Room.

The class is set up as followed:

```
class PlannedEvent {    
   Event baseEvent

   static hasMany = [rooms:Room,equipment:Resource]
   static belongsTo = [Room,Event,Resource]

   static constraints = {
      equipment nullable:true
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a custom JSON Marshaller for your PlannedEvent domain class. Basically you need to implement your own marshller then register it.

Here is an excellent [blog post](http://compiledammit.com/2012/08/16/custom-json-marshalling-in-grails-done-right/) on how to implement your own custom JSON marshalling.

This way you can control exactly how everything gets marsheled into JSON.

Comment: The provided link was helpful, but how can I return different results based on the request so for example: /plannedevents => gives list with no details , /plannedevents/1 => gives detail from plannedevent